# How to disable the right-click context menu on the Chart Control of Office Web Component in a Web Page?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, ole

I want to disable the context menu that pops up when the user right clicks on the interactive Chart control of the Office Web Component in the Web Page. The Web page consists of a Office Web Component interactive chart control and spreadsheet control. This web page is created by using Publish as a web page in excel 2003 for the interactive chart that is embedded in a worksheet. The purpose to disable the toolbar in the context menu on user right click. So as  to not give more control to the user on the interactive chart.

Answer (score 1):

Do this ;) (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

After you publish the workbook as HTM. Right click the HTM file and Open it in Notepad/Notepad++ and add this code right after the `<body>` tag (See snapshot)

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    var message = "Right Click is Disabled";
    function rtclickcheck(keyp){ if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && keyp.which == 3){   alert(message); return false; }
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {  alert(message);     return false; } }
    document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;
</SCRIPT>
```

And you are done :)

**SNAPSHOTS**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**SAMPLE FILE**

http://wikisend.com/download/245080/Desktop.zip

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that to use this method, First save the file to the desktop to make the changes.

Comment: Right click is disabled in the browser but not inside the Chart Component of the published webpage.

Comment: The image of your snap shot has not been uploaded.

Comment: I think I know what could be the problem in your file :) If your workbook has multiple worksheets, then you would need to put that javascript code in the relevent sheetxxx.htm file, instead of the main workbook.htm file itself. :)

Comment: The right click is disabled only in the web browser ie., outside the chart control in the browser but not inside the chart. Just right click inside the chart area. The right click is still not disabled inside the chart control.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8858/discussion-between-laksh-and-siddharth-rout)